# expectations in poisson point process

Tags: point-processes

[image]

here, $\Phi_e$ is a poisson point process and $\eta_k$ a random variable having exponential distribution.

I'm having trouble in understanding how this equality holds?

Comment: Do you understand why $\max(X_1,\dots,X_n) \leq x$ if and only if $(X_1 \leq x \cap\dots\cap X_n \leq x)$ ?

Comment: Also are the $n_k$ related to $e_k$?

Comment: yes, $\eta_k$ is related

Comment: i understand that they are independent and the reason for product operator, but, why is there expectation operator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to understand the link between probability and expectation is the following:

$\begin{align} \mathbb P (\max_{e_k\in\Phi_k}(\eta_k)<x)     &= \mathbb E_{\Phi_k} ( \textbf 1 \{ \max_{e_k\in\Phi_k}(\eta_k)<x \}) \\ & = \mathbb E_{\Phi_k} ( \textbf 1 \{ \bigcap_{e_k\in\Phi_k}\eta_k<x \})  \\ & = \mathbb E_{\Phi_k} ( \prod_{e_k\in\Phi_k} \textbf 1\{\eta_k<x \})  \\ & = \mathbb E_{\Phi_k}\bigg( \prod_{e_k\in\Phi_k} \mathbb P (\eta_k<x )\bigg)  \end{align}$

I only use the independence of the $\eta_k$ (line 2)

Comment: i think now it makes sense, thanks a lot.